# Oracle - How to call a boolean function properly

Tags: oracle, function

I am having a problem executing my boolean function leapyear. I have modified it to return a boolean value but I seem to know how to properly call it.

```
create or replace function leapyear(year IN NUMBER)
RETURN BOOLEAN IS
BEGIN
    IF TO_CHAR(LAST_DAY(TO_DATE('01/02/'||year, 'dd/mm/yyyy')), 'DD') = 29 THEN
        RETURN TRUE;
    ELSE
        RETURN FALSE;
    END IF;
END;
```

The function compiles, but the problem is how to execute it : This shows "
expression is of the wrong type" error

```
DECLARE
    leapy varchar2(10);
BEGIN
    SELECT leapyear(1600) into leapy from dual;
    dbms_output.put_line(leapy);
END;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on;
SQL> begin
  2    if leapyear(1600) then
  3       dbms_output.put_line('Leap year');
  4    else
  5       dbms_output.put_line('Not leap year');
  6    end if;
  7  end;
  8  /
Leap year

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Or:

```
SQL> begin
  2    dbms_output.put_line(case when leapyear(1600) then 'Leap year'
  3                              else 'Not leap year'
  4                         end);
  5  end;
  6  /
Leap year

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

---

Basically, if you want to use that function in pure SQL (i.e. not in PL/SQL), you'd rather return something else such as

- NUMBER (0 being false, 1 being true)
- VARCHAR2 (N being false, Y being true

or similar. Boolean - as datatype - doesn't exist in SQL layer which makes it kind of difficult to use.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use it in an SQL statement as `BOOLEAN` is a [PL/SQL data type](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/datatypes.htm#LNPLS003) and does not exist in [SQL](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF0021).

If you want to return a truthy value in SQL then return a literal (i.e. `0`/`1` or `'Y'`/`'N'` etc.) and compare that if you need to.

```sql
create or replace function leapyear(year IN NUMBER)
RETURN NUMBER IS
BEGIN
    IF TO_CHAR(LAST_DAY(TO_DATE('01/02/'||year, 'dd/mm/yyyy')), 'DD') = 29 THEN
        RETURN 1;
    ELSE
        RETURN 0;
    END IF;
END;
/
```

then just use SQL:

```sql
SELECT leapyear(1600) from dual
```

If you want to use PL/SQL then just use your function and don't context switch to SQL and do it all in PL/SQL:

```sql
BEGIN
  IF leapyear(1600) THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('1600 is a leap year');
  ELSE
    dbms_output.put_line('1600 is not a leap year');
  END IF;
END;
/
```